# UITextViewから任意の文字数だけ文字を削除したい

Tags: swift, ios

#### 環境

swift3
Xcode9.0.1

#### 実現したいこと

UIButtonを押すと、UITextView内のカーソル位置から任意の文字数だけ削除したい。

#### 例

UITextView内に

```
abcdef
```

とありカーソルがfの隣にあったとき、UIButtonを押すと3文字削除し、UITextViewが

```
abc
```

となる

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView`は`UIKeyInput`プロトコル（を継承した`UITextInput`プロトコル）に準拠しているので、`deleteBackward()`メソッドDeleteキーの動作（カーソルの左側の文字を１文字削除する）を実現できます。

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614572-deletebackward